# Update Query Using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I do hope you are well.

I am having a little trouble trying to get my Update query to work, all assisstance welcome.

So I run the Query but it states no rows are updated and I do have records in the original table.

This is my SQL statement.

```
UPDATE tblFuelEntries INNER JOIN tblFuelMaster ON tblFuelEntries.EntryID2 = tblFuelMaster.EntryID2 
SET tblFuelEntries.EntryID2 = [tblFuelMaster]![EntryID2], tblFuelEntries.FillDate = [tblFuelMaster]![FillDate], tblFuelEntries.FleetNo = [tblFuelMaster]![FleetNo], tblFuelEntries.Driver = [tblFuelMaster]![Driver], tblFuelEntries.FillOdo = [tblFuelMaster]![FillOdo], tblFuelEntries.PrevOdo = [tblFuelMaster]![PrevOdo]
WHERE (((tblFuelEntries.PrevOdo)=(SELECT TOP 1 Dup.FillOdo
FROM tblFuelEntries AS Dup
WHERE Dup.FleetNo = tblFuelEntries.FleetNo
AND Dup.FillDate < tblFuelEntries.FillDate
AND Dup.FillOdo < tblFuelEntries.FillOdo)));
```

Basically I am trying to get the statement to find the previous fill odo reading and put it in the current PrevOdo column using an update query.

I managed to get it to work perfectly as a SELECT SQL Statement but cant seem to get it into an UPDATE query.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually no reason to store this. Calculate when needed. Is data in the working SELECT editable?

Comment: It can be I guess but it is dependent on the records that are in the database.
I understand that it is not needed to store but surely it would be better for me to store the values so I can have those values regardless, but more importantly is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. If UPDATE action proves impractical, use VBA manipulating recordset. Edit question to show sample data as text tables.

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  Do you get an error?  Incorrect results?

Comment: No I just dont get any results whatsoever, states (0) rows updated. gonna try that code below and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
UPDATE tblFuelEntries
SET tblFuelEntries.EntryID2 = [tblFuelMaster].[EntryID2],
tblFuelEntries.FillDate = [tblFuelMaster].[FillDate],
tblFuelEntries.FleetNo = [tblFuelMaster].[FleetNo],
tblFuelEntries.Driver = [tblFuelMaster].[Driver],
tblFuelEntries.FillOdo = [tblFuelMaster].[FillOdo],
tblFuelEntries.PrevOdo = [tblFuelMaster].[PrevOdo]

From tblFuelEntries INNER JOIN tblFuelMaster ON tblFuelEntries.EntryID2 = tblFuelMaster.EntryID2 
WHERE tblFuelEntries.PrevOdo= ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Dup.FillOdo
FROM tblFuelEntries AS Dup
WHERE Dup.FleetNo = tblFuelEntries.FleetNo
AND Dup.FillDate < tblFuelEntries.FillDate
AND Dup.FillOdo < tblFuelEntries.FillOdo),0)
```

Comment: States I have a syntax error (missing operator) then highlights the first FROM

also there are no values in the PrevOdo field that is what I am now trying to achieve with this query